# Encrypting a password using gpg without constantly asking for password

Tags: security, password, gpg

I have a service that checks my email regularly, and I use gpg to encrypt my email password. The problem is that every time I lock my computer or after a certain amount of time gpg shows a graphical interface to ask for the password.

Is there a way, even if it's less secure, to have gpg remember my password until I restart my computer? Or perhaps use my log-in password which I have to input anyways to unlock my computer? If that's not possible with gpg, is there another tool that can achieve this?

Comment: What about removing the password from your PGP private key. Even better, you can create a new PGP key-pair without a passphrase and use it only for this purpose; That way if the private key is stolen it could only be used to decrypt that one password.

Comment: That sounds like what I need. Can you provide me with some pointers on how to create a new key-pair without a passphrase? Thanks

Comment: You can use `gpg --quick-gen-key` and simply press ENTER when asked for a passphrase.

Answer (score 1):

GPG can not directly be set to keep the password until restart, but you can change the time it caches the passwords to a very long time, e.g. a year. Add the following lines to `$GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent.conf` (`$GNUPGHOME` is usually `~/.config/gnupg`):

```
default-cache-ttl 31536000
max-cache-ttl 31536000
```

This sets the time for caching passphrases to one year (31536000 seconds). `default-cache-ttl` is the normal caching time, which is reset when the key is used (so on each use it is cached longer), while `max-cache-ttl` limits the total time including extensions.